# Proguard causes 100 "can't find referenced class" warnings, ignores keep rules for springframework and jackson

Tags: android, spring, jackson, proguard, android-proguard

My code compiles and runs fine in debug mode, but once I use a build configuration with minifyEnabled true I get these warnings which prevent compilation:

> Warning:there were 100 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
>
> Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.

For readabilities sake I'll include the full output at the bottom.
There are two libraries that are causing these warnings, springframework and jackson. Those libraries are included in my project via gradle like so:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.5'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5'

apt "org.androidannotations:rest-spring:$AAVersion"
compile "org.androidannotations:rest-spring-api:$AAVersion"     
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
```

If I use -dontwarn for both of these libraries, like many people suggest for these types of issues, the app compiles but crashes with an obfuscated crashlog during startup - I tried retracing it with the mapping file, but that's not working either - I'm reasonably certain that the app crashes due to the autogenerated (through android annotations) class RestClient_ when initializing a jackson mapping class, the exception is the following:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field PUBLIC_ONLY of type
> Lcom/myapp/app/mv$a; in class Lcom/myapp/app/mv$a; or its superclasses
> (declaration of 'com.myapp.app.mv$a' appears in
> /data/app/com.myapp.app-1/base.apk)

Although on a different phone, the exception has no message. It's pretty obvious that this is a result of proguard.

My full proguard file can be found here https://gist.github.com/Syzygy2048/02a44032611d40720bad36b5e3b37db6

---

Here are a couple of things I already tried (I tried more, but I only started writing things down after a while). The attempts focus on fixing springframework first. (Had to put this in a gist because stackoverflow wouldn't let me post otherwise)

https://gist.github.com/Syzygy2048/f1bdabc9f2ea091aa8faec67c62dd8bb

---

full error log:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:myappApp:assembleMyappPublicRelease]
> Warning:org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter: can't find superclass or interface java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport
> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient
> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties
> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient
> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties
> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient
> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties
> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient
> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties
> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.NioPathDeserializer: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.NioPathDeserializer: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Paths
> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.NioPathDeserializer: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.NioPathSerializer: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
> Warning:org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport
> Warning:org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter: can't find referenced method 'void setValue(java.lang.Object)' in program class org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter
> Warning:org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.Object getValue()' in program class org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter
> Warning:org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConvertingPropertyEditorAdapter: can't find referenced class java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntityHC4
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.Configurable
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig$Builder
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGetHC4
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDeleteHC4
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHeadHC4
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptionsHC4
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPostHC4
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPutHC4
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpTraceHC4
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPatch
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig$Builder
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.EntityUtilsHC4
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.util.EntityUtilsHC4
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpResponse: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsStreamingClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient
> Warning:org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsStreamingClientHttpRequest: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse
> Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister
> Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.simpleframework.xml.Root
> Warning:org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter: can't find referenced class org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer
> Warning:there were 100 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
> Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
> Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
> Error:Execution failed for task ':myappApp:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForMyappPublicRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
> Information:BUILD FAILED
> Information:Total time: 23.68 secs
> Information:1 error
> Information:59 warnings
> Information:See complete output in console

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that adding this to my proguard file fixed my issues.

> -keepclassmembers class com.myapp.models.** {
>       *; }
>
> -keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.** { *; }
>
> -dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
>
> -dontwarn org.springframework.**

So in the end I could ignore most of those warnings after all. As I said simply ignoring them lead to crashes, which are fixed by not obfuscating jackson annotations and by not obfuscating my model classes which seem to be needed so that the json <--> pojo conversion can happen.